# Power BI Dynamic Legend

Tags: powerbi

I'm working with a geographical hierarchy.  I'd like for the Legend on my line or ribbon chart to show the next lowest relevant level of detail based upon a slicer selection.

**GOAL:**
No Slicer Selection yields a Regional Chart (lines for Southeast, Northeast, etc).  Select "Northeast" Region from Slicer yields a State Chart (lines for Maine, New Hampshire, etc.) Select "Maine" State from Slicer yields a County Chart, and so forth.

I can do this in a Card using a combination of HASONEVALUE and VALUES to obtain a dynamic single value.  However, the Legend field of Ribbon or Line Charts will not accept such a measure.

Is there any way to create a Power BI Line or Ribbon chart with a dynamic Legend based upon slicer selection?

I'd rather not create a separate measure for all hierarchy nodes as there are thousands of possible leaves.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's say I have some population data on the largest 20 US counties as follows:

```
Data = DATATABLE(
       "Rank", INTEGER, "Region", STRING, "County", STRING, "State", STRING,
       "2010", INTEGER, "2012", INTEGER, "2014", INTEGER,
       {{1,"West","Los Angeles","California",9818605,9826773,9826773},
        {2,"Midwest","Cook","Illinois",5194675,5199971,5199971},
        {3,"South","Harris","Texas",4092459,4109362,4109362},
        {4,"South","Maricopa","Arizona",3817117,3824834,3824834},
        {5,"West","San Diego","California",3095313,3105115,3105115},
        {6,"West","Orange","California",3010232,3017598,3017598},
        {7,"South","Miami-Dade","Florida",2496435,2503034,2503034},
        {8,"Northeast","Kings","New York",2504700,2508515,2508515},
        {9,"South","Dallas","Texas",2368139,2375207,2375207},
        {10,"Northeast","Queens","New York",2230722,2233895,2233895},
        {11,"West","Riverside","California",2189641,2202978,2202978},
        {12,"West","San Bernardino","California",2035210,2042027,2042027},
        {13,"West","King","Washington",1931249,1937157,1937157},
        {14,"West","Clark","Nevada",1951269,1953927,1953927},
        {15,"South","Tarrant","Texas",1809034,1816850,1816850},
        {16,"West","Santa Clara","California",1781642,1786267,1786267},
        {17,"South","Broward","Florida",1748066,1752122,1752122},
        {18,"South","Bexar","Texas",1714773,1723561,1723561},
        {19,"Midwest","Wayne","Michigan",1820584,1815246,1815246},
        {20,"Northeast","New York","New York",1585873,1587481,1587481}
       })
```

Using this data as a source in the query editor, we will produce two tables. The first will be a `Fact` table that unpivots the years and looks like this for the top three counties:

[image: Top 3 Counties]

The second will be a `Bridge` table that's just a list of unique `Region`, `State`, `County` combinations:

[image: Bridge Table]

We'll create one final table using DAX. This will be our `Legend` table.

```
Legend = UNION(SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Fact[Region], Fact[Rank], "Level", 1),
             SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Fact[State], Fact[Rank],  "Level", 2),
             SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Fact[County], Fact[Rank],  "Level", 3)
             )
```

Make sure the relationships are set on the `Rank` columns so that your relationship diagram looks like this:

[image: Relationship Diagram]

Now we'll write a measure that takes advantage of these levels that we just created in the `Legend` table.

```
Measure = 
    VAR StateCount = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Bridge[State]),
                         ALLSELECTED(Bridge), ALLSELECTED(Legend))
    VAR RegionCount = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Bridge[Region]),
                          ALLSELECTED(Bridge), ALLSELECTED(Legend))
    VAR LevelNumber = SWITCH(TRUE(), StateCount = 1, 3, RegionCount = 1, 2, 1)
    RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(Fact[Population]), Legend[Level] = LevelNumber)
```

Basically, we only want to show the population for the appropriate level.

Using this measure on a line chart with `Legend[Region]` in the legend box and `Fact[Year]` on the axis, the result looks like this when slicers are left blank:

[image: No Selections]

When we select a region and then a state, we get the following:

[image: Region][image: State]

---

Here's a link to the PBIX file I created for this: [Variable Legend.pbix](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wzQYqCaoP_3sRw2VQoT6kfBtNTF_xAcC)

Comment: I'm having trouble editing the New Table added via Datatable DAX command.  The Query Editor seems to only want to edit live connection data.

Comment: Yeah, a DAX calculated table won't get passed back the query editor. You can copy and paste it into a table via Enter Data though.

Comment: If anyone tries to recreate this, it should be noted that Report Slicers must be created from Bridge[Region] or Bridge[State].  Slicers on Fact[Region] will not have the desired effect.  This is a very nice solution for sales organizations with regional middle managers.

Comment: Also, note that when you try to unpivot the Data Table to create Fact Table you will get an error message related to breaking the Primary Key.  See this post for resolution - https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/change-primary-key-power-bi/m-p/51711#M20773

Comment: Also note that this doesn't work properly with multi-select slicer. @AlexisOlson, please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I know it is an older post, but can it be used for 100%Stacked column chart too? Would it be similar approach or? Lets say I have like 4x main groups and many subgroups and would like to filter it out with corresponding legends. Thx

Comment: @MmVv I don't see why a 100% chart would be different. However, you may want to look into Field Parameters too (this is a newer feature). https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/fields-parameters-in-power-bi/